# GUI for Amazon Simple Email Service?

Tags: gui

i'm looking for a GUI for Amazon Simple Email Service, which displays stats of sent mails. Does someone know any?

Comment: Are you looking for desktop software or web software? If you want desktop software, the question is fine for Super User, but if you want a web application, it would be better for [webapps.se].

Answer (score 1):

This is meanwhile available within the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), see [Amazon SES Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#ses) specifically:

> The Amazon SES Management Console is a simple and intuitive web-based
>   user interface for Amazon SES that allows you to do common SES
>   management functions with a few clicks of your mouse. **These include
>   checking your sending quota and usage**; seeing your Amazon SES bounce,
>   complaint, and rejection metrics over time; verifying sender email
>   addresses; and sending both formatted and raw test emails. *[emphasis mine]*

You might want to read the introductory post [New - AWS Management Console Support for the Simple Email Service](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/10/new-aws-management-console-support-for-the-simple-email-service.html) as well for a quick overview.